# Jquery UI Sortable get Position Parent and Children

Tags: jquery

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/johndavemanuel/htLx358f/17/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    // Sort the parents
    $(".sortable").sortable({
        containment: "parent",
        items: "> div",
        handle: ".move",
        tolerance: "pointer",
        cursor: "move",
        opacity: 0.7,
        revert: 300,
        delay: 150,
        dropOnEmpty: true,
        placeholder: "movable-placeholder",
        start: function(e, ui) {
            ui.placeholder.height(ui.helper.outerHeight());
        }
    });
    
    // Sort the children
    $(".group-items").sortable({
        containment: "document",
        items: "> div",
        connectWith: '.group-items'
    });
    
})
```

I have 3 DIV that acts as parent and it is sortable
and inside of them has other DIV as act as the children,

I is working fine I can sort the parents and children, my issue is how can I get the "serialize" position of all them like this

Parent 2

Child 1

Child 4

---

Parent 1

Child 2

Child 5

---

Parent 3

Child 3

Child 6

---

I will be using that to save their position so when user came back it will be like that

Any  help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to do this in the jQuery UI directly, but... You can use here `.index()` method (https://api.jquery.com/index/index) which will give you the zero-based position of the element.

Comment: I dont know how can I put that

Comment: Morning Dave Manuel. Please check this one: http://jsfiddle.net/ddziaduch/ajdm6p2r/25/

Comment: I already come up with a solution! but thanks I will check your solution

Comment: Howdy Dave, please share your solution :)

Comment: I think my question title is kinda general, so I just need an array or JSON of the fields, so I post my solution below

Answer (score 0):

```
function createArrayFromSortableList() {
    var sortables = $(".group-caption");
    sortables.each(function() {
        var fields = [];
        $(this).find('div.group-item.field').each(function() {
            fields.push({
                id: $(this).attr("data-id"),
                sectionID: $(this).closest(".group-caption").find('.section-title').attr("data-id"),
                fieldName: $.trim($(this).find(".field-name").text().replace(/[\t\n]+/g, ' ')),
                fieldPosition: $(this).closest(".group-items").attr("data-column")
            });

        });
        sections.push({
            id: $(this).find('.section-title').attr("id"),
            sectionName: $(this).find('.section-title').text(),
            zfields: fields
        });


    });
    console.log(sections);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(sections));
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]